# FB Graph API explorer, center params not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get all parties list in Bangalore using graph API. I am using following graph query

```
search?q=parties&type=event&center=12.9716,77.5946&distance=10000
```

in facebook graph explorer

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895
```

Though I am giving Bangalore lat and long, I am getting results from different cities

for example first result I am getting is from **Barcelona**

```
 "city": "Barcelona",
 "country": "Spain",
 "latitude": 41.384918007029,
 "longitude": 2.1618401413727,
 "street": "Gran Via de Les Corts Catalanes 571",
 "zip": "08011"
```

[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search carefully, you’ll notice that these parameters are listed for the search type `place` only.

You can not use these parameters when searching for events. Passing them anyway achieves nothing, they are simply ignored.

The most you can do, is include `Bangalore` in your search term, to only search for events that have that city name included in their title.